# Autoplay for slides in the fullPage.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

How can I implement autoplay for slides if use the [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) plugin?

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section">
  <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div>
  <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
  <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div>
</div>
<div class="section">Some section</div>
<div class="section">Some section</div>
```

Comment: Hi Samoilenko. Welcome to SO. I've inserted a link to the plugin. Please check that it is the one you are using. You cannot always assume people will know what you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a junior on this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Google and type "autoplay fullpage.js".
Click on [the first result](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/725) and follow the instructions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/119/)